# jQuery - Append hash to href from current URL

Tags: html, jquery, anchor, url-fragment

Let's say I have this URL in the address bar:

> [www.example.com/pt.html#myhash](http://www.example.com/pt.html#myhash)

Also I have an anchor that links to

```
<a id="lang" href="https://www.example.com/en.html">Change Language</a>
```

What I wanted to archive is to append to that anchor the #myhash tag but only if it's present in the current URL. If not, don't append anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `window.location.hash` is set and that it isn't just a `'#'` then apply to the anchor

```js
// for demo only set hash
history.pushState(null, null, '#someVal')


const urlHash = location.hash,
     langLink = document.querySelector('#lang');

if (urlHash && urlHash !== '#') {
  langLink.hash = urlHash; 
}

console.log('New href=',langLink.href)
```

```html
<a id="lang" href="https://www.example.com/en.html">Change Language</a>
```

Comment: But what if the hash tag changes while on the same page? I have several #ids that the user can select on that page. The"lang" link does not get updated.

Comment: You can listen to `hashchange` event https://jsfiddle.net/swt94zf1/